# Any reason why I'm getting 413, when the the request body isn't too large?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, put

Using Java/Jersey to submit a PUT request containing a bodypart of json, and one PDF, not encoded in Base64 and as part of a multipart request. FilePart is 96Kb. I'm really just looking for a place to start, I've debugged everything, no errors, just getting a 413 Request Too Large back.

The company I've been trying to submit the request to, is adament that this works using postman.

Can I ask, does Jersey send a lot more data than they log using;

```
.property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_CLIENT, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY)
.property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_CLIENT, "INFO");
```

I can see the request body and he binaries being sent, but apart from that, is there any reason Jersey doesn't end up sending the same thing as say Postman, or Insomnia?

Implementation;

```
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
ctx.init(null, certs(), new SecureRandom());

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ctx.getSocketFactory());
HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier = (String string, SSLSession ssls) -> true;

ClientBuilder clientBuilder = JerseyClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                                                     .register(MultiPartFeature.class)
                                                     .register(MultiPartWriter.class)
                                                     .register(JacksonJsonProvider.class)
                                                     .sslContext(ctx)
                                                     .hostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier)
                                                     .property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_VERBOSITY_CLIENT, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY)
                                                     .property(LoggingFeature.LOGGING_FEATURE_LOGGER_LEVEL_CLIENT, "INFO");

Client client = clientBuilder.build();
final MediaType mediaType = new MediaType("multipart", "form-data");
MultiPart multipartEntity = new MultiPart().type(mediaType);

t = client.target(this.getBaseUri()).path(this.resource);

if (items != null && !items.isEmpty())
{
        for (Object item : items)
        {
            FileItem fItem = (FileItem) item;

            if (fItem.getContentType() != null && (fItem.getContentType().contains("application/pdf") || fItem.getContentType().contains("text/html")))
            {
                byte[] imageByteArray = fItem.getString().getBytes("UTF-8");

                String fileName = fItem.getName();
                String contentId = null;

                if (fileName != null)
                {
                    fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(fileName);
                }

                if (fItem.getFieldName().contains("address"))
                {
                    contentId = "someContent";
                }
                else if (fItem.getFieldName().contains("id"))
                {
                    contentId = "someOtherContent";
                }

                String tempFileName = "/home/temp/" + fileName;
                tempFileNames.add(tempFileName);

                fsOut = new FileOutputStream(tempFileName);

                fsOut.write(imageByteArray);
                FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart(fItem.getFieldName(), new File(tempFileName), MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE);

                filePart.getHeaders().add("Content-Id", contentId);
                files.add(filePart);
            }
        }

        if (!files.isEmpty())
        {
            if (files.size() == 1)
            {
                FileDataBodyPart part = (FileDataBodyPart)files.get(0);
                part.getHeaders().add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

                multipartEntity = new FormDataMultiPart()
                    .bodyPart(body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .bodyPart(part);
            }
            else if (files.size() == 2)
            {
                FileDataBodyPart part1 = (FileDataBodyPart)files.get(0), part2 = (FileDataBodyPart)files.get(0);
                part1.getHeaders().add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                part2.getHeaders().add("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");

                multipartEntity = new FormDataMultiPart()
                    .bodyPart(body, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                    .bodyPart(part1)
                    .bodyPart(part2);
            }

            if (fsOut != null)
            {
                fsOut.close();
            }
        }

        if (multipartEntity != null)
        {
            String auth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode((AUTHNAME + ":" + AUTHKEY).getBytes()));

    response = t.request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                  .header("Authorization", auth)
                                  .put(Entity.entity(multipartEntity, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));
        }
```

Is there something I'm doing which can reduce the size of the request?

Comment: Rather than trust what the adamant partner claims, why not make the request with Postman yourself? Or cUrl or whatever.

Comment: Then implement a server yourself (e.g. a simple Spring Boot app) using plain HTTP, and use WireShark to compare what your client does with what Postman does.

Comment: cheers! I would do that but the url is https, hence the SSL context.

Comment: Hence running up your own non-SSL mock server, so you can WireShark. Wiremock is another easy way to make a mock server.